# given an infinite sequence break it into intervals, and return a new infinite sequence with the average of each interval

Tags: java, algorithm, functional-programming, java-stream

i have to calculate the average of a Infinite Sequence using Stream API

Input:

```
Stream<Double> s = a,b,c,d ...
int interval = 3
```

Expected Result:

```
Stream<Double> result = avg(a,b,c), avg(d,e,f), ....
```

the result can be also an Iterator, or any other type
as long as it mantains the structure of an infinite list

of course what i written is pseudo code and doesnt run

Comment: Is your question about framing an API something like `Stream<Double> stepAverage(Stream<Double> stream, int step)`? What's the use case, could you please elaborate?

Comment: does it need to be threadsafe or not?

Comment: no, it is okay even if it's not thread safe

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. Does the stream at least have `SUBSIZED` characteristics for its Spliterator?

Comment: There is a safe way to achieve this but the algorithm is `O(3n)` using stream API. While stream API is suitable for most of the common scenarios there are some corner cases. The above requirement is best handled in the traditional way.

Comment: @Naman sorry you're right, i unchecked

Comment: @AniketSahrawat can you show, to be honest here it doesnt matter the complexity, but to achieve this in the shortest amount of lines

Comment: @florentinnica https://ideone.com/tkRcok

Comment: @AniketSahrawat thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `@Beta` API termed [**`mapWithIndex`**](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/30.1-jre/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#mapWithIndex(java.util.stream.Stream,com.google.common.collect.Streams.FunctionWithIndex)) within Guava that could help here with certain assumption:

```
static Stream<Double> stepAverage(Stream<Double> stream, int step) {
    return Streams.mapWithIndex(stream, (from, index) -> Map.entry(index, from))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> (e.getKey() / step), TreeMap::new,
                    Collectors.averagingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)))
            .values().stream();
}
```

The assumption that it brings in is detailed in the documentation clearly(emphasized by me):

> The resulting stream is efficiently splittable **if and only if stream
> was efficiently splittable and its underlying spliterator reported
> `Spliterator.SUBSIZED`**. This is generally the case if the underlying
> stream comes from a data structure supporting efficient indexed random
> access, typically an array or list.

Comment: Note that if the stream is Infinite, you wont be able to collect it

Comment: @YassinHajaj Of course, infinite streams are supposed to be limited before collecting them to avoid OOMs.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine using vanilla Java

I'm using `Stream#mapMulti` and a `Set` external to the `Stream` to aggregate the doubles

As you see, I also used `DoubleSummaryStatistics` to count the average.
I could have use the traditional looping and summing then dividing but I found this way more explicit

Update:
I changed the `Collection` used from `Set` to `List` as a `Set` could cause unexpected behaviour

```java
int step = 3;
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
Stream<Double> averagesStream =
        infiniteStream.mapMulti(((Double aDouble, Consumer<Double> doubleConsumer) -> {
            list.add(aDouble);
            if (list.size() == step) {
                DoubleSummaryStatistics doubleSummaryStatistics = new DoubleSummaryStatistics();
                list.forEach(doubleSummaryStatistics::accept);
                list.clear();
                doubleConsumer.accept(doubleSummaryStatistics.getAverage());
            }
        }));
```

Comment: I kind of like this solution, and also not. The use of an external `Set` seems somewhat fishy to me

Comment: I know @Lino, but there is no other way to get there without it, you could use Collectors but then you would need to terminate your `Stream` unfortunately..

Comment: Isn't the question about framing something like `Stream<Double> stepAverage(Stream<Double> stream, int step)`? The infinite stream here is generated by you, right?

Comment: @YassinHajaj, thank you very much, can you show me the way also using Collectors, in the end it doesnt matter the result, just needs to be an iterator or Stream

Comment: fyi, your solution doesn't work with the updated code

Comment: @Naman what do you mean it does not work? If you mean `infiniteStream` does not exist, it's done on purpose

Comment: @florentinnica you could collect then regenerate a `Stream` would that work for you?

Comment: @YassinHajaj, yes it would be okay, also without regenerating the stream

Comment: But then it's not an infinite stream, are you understanding this? Because an infinite Stream cannot end on an aggregation terminal operation

Comment: I meant if `infiniteStream` is of type `Stream<Double>`, the code above wouldn't compile.

Comment: Correct indeed ;)